# how to run a query in c without mysql_free_result(res)

Tags: mysql, c, c-api

```
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) {

    sprintf(statement, "DELETE FROM `outgoing` WHERE `outgoing`.`id`=%s", row[0]);

    if (mysql_query(conn, statement)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));    
    }
}
```

I am getting `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` error

Comment: Your single quote isn't the right single quote. It must be '.

Comment: Please post more code, in particular, show the first `mysql_query`.

Comment: this is the first query   ==> mysql_query(conn, "SELECT * FROM `outgoing` WHERE `status` = '1' LIMIT 0, 10");

Comment: Please edit your question and include all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably use [`mysql_use_result()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-use-result.html) function to get results from MySQL database. In that case, rows are sent to client one-by-one, when `mysql_fetch_row()` is called. Until all rows are fetched, database handle is "locked":

> When using `mysql_use_result()`, you must execute `mysql_fetch_row()`
>   until a NULL value is returned, otherwise, the unfetched rows are
>   returned as part of the result set for your next query. The C API
>   gives the error `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`
>   if you forget to do this!

Try [`mysql_store_result()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-store-result.html) as replacement. That function fetches all rows at once.

Comment: i need to run another query inside that while nothing else

Answer (score -1):

The correct statement is:

```
sprintf(statement, "DELETE FROM outgoing WHERE outgoing.id='%s'", row[0]);
```

Note the correct quote around the `%s` and note that the other stuff needs NO quotes as they are names, not values.

Comment: i need to run two queries , one is inside while loop

Comment: So? Just run the query and `sprintf` statement in the loop. And I don't know what you are fetching but maybe you need to address a field in your `row[0]`. And maybe the queries interfere with each other if you fetch from the same table you are deleting from. Anyway, the above statement is correct. Show more code to make us understand the error in more detail.